# Date Picker is not getting displayed on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use DatePicker of Jquery UI for Text Field. It is not getting displayed on the first Click but on unfocus and focus it is displaying. 
here is sample code with which i am trying.I am confused with why it is not firsttime only.

Html

```
<tr><td>Text Field:</td><td><input type="text" name="sampleDate" id="sampleDate" onfocus="showDatePicker(this)"/></td></tr>
```

JavaScript :

```
function showDatePicker(element)
{   
$(element).datepicker();    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats because you are assigning the datepicker on focus , instead add to click event callback

Comment: do you get any errors? use firebug or any other browser-inspector. and then please post your error

Comment: Helle. No Errors.i am debugging it in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution updated on

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9N7K/9/)

For this solution assuming each field which is going to display calander having calss "date", there is no need to attach `onclick` event

```
<tr>
    <td>Text Field:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="sampleDate" class="date" id="sampleDate" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

attaching event to each input element having class date

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( ".date" ).each(function( index ) {
       $( this ).datepicker();
   });

});
```

---

try onclick event

```
onClick="showDatePicker(this)"
```

easily solution is to make use of [**Datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Still the problem exists but no errors.  Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L9N7K/7/

Comment: Pranay, could you pls check your fiddle as well. when run it first time it is not showing the datepicker. unfocus and click once again, then only it is showing.

Comment: @Venkat - i am having same problem but there is alternate solution provided by me check jsfiddle link in my answer

Comment: If Venkat has the access to add class this is the easy solution.

Comment: I've just changed a bit the jsFiddle of +Pranay Rana : is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/L9N7K/16/

Comment: Thanks for your input. it is working. could you pls suggest a comment why it is not working for first time when i tried on other way.

Comment: The first time you are calling `datepicker` it setups the widget. From the second time on ward it will open the datepicker itself...

Answer (score 0):

Because on first focus the datepicker is not getting defined

This will give an error

```
Uncaught excpetion: showDatePicker is not defined
```

A simple solution will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sampleDate').datepicker();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9N7K/5/)

Comment: Here the problem is name of text field is dynamically defined and created on the fly in JSP .Few text fields are not date fields. for your reference the sample name/id of the text field will be like this .. <tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type="text" name="parameterList[5].paramValue" value="11/11/2013" /></td></tr>. so i have to specify the onclick functionality to Date field based on some condition

Comment: @Venkat Do you have any patterns for the `name` or `id`?  like name always starts with xxx

Comment: Onclick as well i am seeing the same issue. intention is not to depend on the patterns so that maintenance of code will be troublesome. if i specify on click functionality, it will be easy to understand and maintenance as well.suggestions are welcome and will make note of it.